# Stroking bounding boxes with Prawn

Tags: ruby, prawn

I have some variable-length text that I'm inserting into a Prawn bounding box. Depending on the length of the text, the result will be any number of pages long, each with a bounding box. I want each of these bounding boxes stroked. I can stroke the first box and the last box, but can't figure out how to stroke the ones in the middle...

```
  bounding_box([0, 500], :width => 200, :height => 150) do
    stroke_bounds # This will stroke the first box
    text "This text will fill up many boxes. " * 100
    stroke_bounds # This will stroke the last box
  end
```